# django Date time input

Tags: python, django

I need that in my castration form in the part of chckin and checkout it appears a calendar with date and time, so that the usurario does not have to type manually, I tried using widgets, but the input of the form appears like normal input.
And I need the calencario with day, month, year and hour and minute

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import math

class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=False,)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    valor_hora = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(
        Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime'
 class MovRotativoForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
     model = MovRotativo
     fields = '__all__'
     widgets = {
         'checkin':  DateTimeInput(),
         'checkout': DateTimeInput(),
    }
```